# How to apply PCA in R with using data with a factor in its first column?

Tags: r

My data is composed of 16 columns. The first one is a factor. The rest of my columns are a set of numerical numbers. 
When i have applied the PCA method in R , I found that PCA can not be applied on my data.frame because this latter contains factors in the first column.

```
library(FactoMineR)
data(MyData)
res.pca = PCA(MyData[,1:10], scale.unit=TRUE, ncp=5, graph=T)
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error in colMeans(X, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
And : Warning message:
In PCA(data, scale.unit = TRUE, ncp = 5, graph = T) :
Missing values are imputed by the mean of the variable: you should use the 
imputePCA function of the missMDA package
```

When I changed the first colums which was recently declared as a factor with a set of numerical numbers, that works and it gives me good results. I can plot all correlation axes only with number in my axes while I need factors not numbers.
I would be very grateful if you could help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You should mention that your first column is a factor .
So try to do this :

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(missMDA)
data(MyData)
## Imputation
res <- imputePCA(MyData[,2:10],ncp=5)
mydata=cbind(myData[,1],res$completeObs)
res.pca = PCA(mydata,quali.sup=1, scale.unit=TRUE, ncp=5, graph=T)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works but it still give me number behind each  individual factor, and it gives me this warning too: Warning message:
In PCA(data, quali.sup = 1, scale.unit = TRUE, ncp = 5, graph = T) :
  Missing values are imputed by the mean of the variable: you should use the imputePCA function of the missMDA package

Comment: that mean you have missing values `NA` in your data and it propose to use a function to impute the data i will change the answer to better understanding

Comment: thank you for your answer, when I plot the correlation figure, the individual factor doesn't appear, so in my figure, I have   v112, v102, v89,  however at first, I have the indiidual factor name.